# JQuery Data table paging buttons scrunched together when bjqueryui is true

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, datatable

Here's my data table...

```
 oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
       "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        //"sDom": 'R<"H"Tlfr>t<"F"ip>',
        // "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetAllDonors", "Person")',
        /* Reduced data set */
        "bProcessing": true,
         "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings) {
            $(oTable.fnGetNodes()).click(function () {
                var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
                var aData = oSettings.aoData[iPos]._aData;
                location.href = '/Person/Details?id=' + aData[0];
                //alert('Data at index 0: '+aData[0]);
            });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
        { "bVisible": false },
        { "sTitle": "Name" },
        { "sTitle": "Address" },
        { "sTitle": "Phone" },
        { "sTitle": "Email" },
        { "sTitle": "Company" }
    ]

    });
});
```

when I enable the ui theme, the paging buttons get pushed together so some are overlapping/can't click on them. Any thoughts?

Here's a screen shot of what it looks like: [image]

Comment: looks like this is likly to be a CSS issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the script src for jquery.ui javascript and css files to your document.